# PHP Operator <= returns true if array is empty

Tags: php

I use PHP operators <= to determine if a user has permissions to se data.

```
if($_SESSION['usr']['permissions'] <= 5){
```

My problem occurs when $_SESSION is empty. Then the statement is true.
$_SESSION is always declared as a array, so it will always be less than 5.

How should i code this to not accept empty sessions?
if $_SESSION is an empty array i like the statement to become false.

Ive tried:

```
if($_SESSION['usr']['permissions'] <== 5){
```

But of corse <== doesn't exist.

Should i use something like:

```
if($_SESSION['usr']['permissions'] <= 5 && $_SESSION.length > 0){
```

Comment: `if(isset($_SESSION['usr']['permissions']) && $_SESSION['usr']['permissions'] <= 5)`?

Comment: why not use this ? `if(isset($_SESSION['usr']['permissions']) && $_SESSION['usr']['permissions'] < 5){}`

Comment: If array is empty, may it is getting cast to 0 and that is why you are getting true.

Comment: `! empty($_SESSION['usr']['permissions']) && $_SESSION['usr']['permissions'] < 5` should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My problem occurs when $_SESSION is empty

Check if it's empty or not :

```
if(!empty($_SESSION['usr']['permissions']) && $_SESSION['usr']['permissions'] <= 5){
```

Now if you can have `$_SESSION['usr']['permissions'] = 0`, you should do :

```
if(isset($_SESSION['usr']['permissions']) && $_SESSION['usr']['permissions'] <= 5){
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check first if it is set first

```
  if(isset($_SESSION['usr']['permissions']) && $_SESSION['usr']['permissions'] <= 5) 
   {
     Do stuff
    }
```